# How to give CSS attributes to new labels that have not been fully defined?

Tags: java, javafx, attributes, grid-layout, gridpane

I have a system of which creates a new Label in Javafx that is predefined but is just created on the spot whenever a method is ran.
I want to be able to edit the background color of the label(s) that are created.

```
countSendResponses++
mainLayout.add(new Label(messageSend), 0, countSendResponces).Color.rgb(1, 1, 1);
// that gives an error, I have tried the same thing in different places in that line of code. Nothing works
```

My current code:
    countSendResponses++
    mainLayout.add(new Label(messageSend), 0, countSendResponces);

Is there a way to do this? If there is a better way to do what I am doing I am open to suggestions. I want to be able to change the background color of the label. Thank you!

Comment: messageSend is equal to the message that I want to be sent. I don't think that needs any code to explain that as it is only the string placed within the label. I will give that code if needed though.

Comment: Just store the `Label` in a local variable before adding/modifying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the CSS style of any node in JavaFX, you need to use `Node.setStyle("//Insert CSS Here.");`

For example, to change the background color of a text, you can use:

```
Node.setStyle("
   -fx-background-color: red;
");
```

For a complete reference guide for using CSS in JavaFX, you can go here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor

Remember that when using CSS in JavaFX, you always have to start every attribute with `-fx-`.